# Custom ID for certain menu item?

Tags: menus, navigation, logo

I'm displaying Wordpress menu using this function:

```
wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

Menu is set in wp-admin/nav-menus.php.

Can I somehow attach ID of my choice to one of the items? I want the menu to look like:

[ Link 1 ] [ Link 2] [ LOGO (that is Link 3 also ] [ Link 4 ] [ Link 5]

I know I could style ID of the logo link such as "menu-item-123", but I'd love to change it to "logo" or something that has a meaning :)

Thanks.

Comment: Look into using a custom nav walker http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the "Class"-field for styling. Give it a unique class, target it in your CSS file. Done.

> [image: WordPress menu item class]

Comment: Thanks for the screen, I was looking for the "class" field but couldn't find it!

Comment: And another big *thanks!* to the WordPress crew for "helping" developers out by hiding important functionality in obscure places.